# Obtaining correct data using Regex/List

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am parsing the following code using a regex (not ideal I know, but that is a story for another day):

```
data:{
            url: 'stage-team-stat'
        },
        defaultParams: {
            stageId : 9155,
            field: 2,
            teamId: 26
        }
    };
```

This is being parsed using the following code (where var is the above code):

```
import re

    stagematch = re.compile("data:\s*{\s*url:\s*'stage-team-stat'\s*},\s*defaultParams:\s*{\s*(.*?),.*},",re.S)

    stagematch2 = re.search(stagematch, var)

        if stagematch2 is not None:
            stagematch3 = stagematch2.group(1)

            stageid = int(stagematch3.split(':', 1)[1])
            stageid = str(stageid)

            teamid = int(stagematch3.split(':', 3)[1])
            teamid = str(teamid)

            print stageid
            print teamid
```

In this example I would expect `stageid` to be '9155' and `teamid` to be '32', however they are both coming back as '9155'.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of dumping all of your code, can you give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has just the few lines that actually matter, and includes the relevant input data instead of making us crawl an entire website to get it?

Comment: @user3045351 I guess @abarnert meant to have a code snippet that clearly demonstrates the problem without even `scrapy` being involved here. Cause, strictly speaking, the question is not scrapy-specific, but more about "how to extract certain fields from a string that is a snippet of javascript code".

Comment: It's _better_ now… but still not very good. The code isn't runnable with indentation errors all over the place. And why not just put the variable into the code instead of describing how to do it?

Comment: As a side note, if you use `re.compile`, you get back a regex object that you can use directly: `stagematch.match(var)`, not `re.match(stagematch, var)`.

Comment: Meanwhile, when I run this code against that data, the `re.search` returns `None`. So, it's not actually demonstrating your problem at all.

Comment: One last thing: I haven't looked over the whole thing, but you've got a regex with a bunch of backslashes, and they aren't escaped, and it's not a raw string literal. You will get away with that for some letters, but not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution would be not to dive into regexes, but parse javascript code with a javascript code parser. Example using [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit):

> SlimIt is a JavaScript minifier written in Python. It compiles
>   JavaScript into more compact code so that it downloads and runs
>   faster.
>
> SlimIt also provides a library that includes a JavaScript parser,
>   lexer, pretty printer and a tree visitor.

```
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

data = """
var defaultTeamStatsConfigParams = {
        data:{
            url: 'stage-team-stat'
        },
        defaultParams: {
            stageId : 9155,
            field: 2,
            teamId: 32
        }
    };

    DataStore.prime('stage-team-stat', defaultTeamStatsConfigParams.defaultParams, [{"RegionId":252,"RegionCode":"gb-eng","TournamentName":"Premier League","TournamentId":2,"StageId":9155,"Field":{"Value":2,"DisplayName":"Overall"},"TeamName":"Manchester United","TeamId":32,"GamesPlayed":4,"Goals":6,"Yellow":7,"Red":0,"TotalPasses":2480,"Possession":247,"AccuratePasses":2167,"AerialWon":61,"AerialLost":49,"Rating":7.01,"DefensiveRating":7.01,"OffensiveRating":6.79,"ShotsConcededIBox":13,"ShotsConcededOBox":21,"TotalTackle":75,"Interceptions":71,"Fouls":54,"WasFouled":46,"TotalShots":49,"ShotsBlocked":9,"ShotsOnTarget":19,"Dribbles":44,"Offsides":3,"Corners":17,"Throws":73,"Dispossesed":36,"TotalClearance":78,"Turnover":0,"Ranking":0}]);

    var stageStatsConfig = {
        id: 'team-stage-stats',
        singular: true,
        filter: {
                instanceType: WS.Filter,
                id: 'team-stage-stats-filter',
                categories: { data: [{ value: 'field' }] },
                singular: true
        },
        params: defaultTeamStatsConfigParams,
        content: {
            instanceType: TeamStageStats,
            view: {
                renderTo: 'team-stage-stats-content'
            }
        }
    };

    var stageStats = new WS.Panel(stageStatsConfig);
    stageStats.load();
"""

parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(data)
fields = {getattr(node.left, 'value', ''): getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
          for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
          if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)}

print fields['stageId'], fields['field'], fields['teamId']
```

Prints `9155 2 32`.

Here we are iterating over the syntax tree nodes and constructing a dictionary from all assignments. Among them we have `stageId`, `fields` and `teamId`.

---

Here is how you can apply the solution to your scrapy spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


def get_fields(data):
    parser = Parser()
    tree = parser.parse(data)
    return {getattr(node.left, 'value', ''): getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
            for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
            if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)}


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/Statistics/England-Manchester-United"]
    download_delay = 5

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/Statistics/England-Manchester-United'),deny=('/News', '/Graphics', '/Articles', '/Live', '/Matches', '/Explanations', '/Glossary', 'ContactUs', 'TermsOfUse', 'Jobs', 'AboutUs', 'RSS'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        myheader = titles.extract()[0]

        script = sel.xpath('//div[@id="team-stage-stats"]/following-sibling::script/text()').extract()[0]
        script_fields = get_fields(script)
        print script_fields['stageId'], script_fields['field'], script_fields['teamId']
```

Comment: thanks, that did what i wanted. i wont pretend i understoof all of it straight away though, so i will have to do some further reading. thanks